# Как передавать параметры в React + TypeScript из родительского в дочерний компонент

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В родительском компоненте есть метод:

```
private handleLoginFormChange = (name: string) =>(e: any) => {
   const newState = cloneDeep(this.state);
   const newValue = e.target.value;
   set(newState, name, newValue);
   this.setState(newState);
  }
```

Его передаем в дочерний компонент. Дочерний компонент - форма логина.

```
<LoginForm 
 submitLogin={this.handleLoginForm}
 onChangeForm={this.handleLoginFormChange}
 />
```

Дочерний компонент написан в функциональном стиле.

```
interface Props {
  submitLogin?: () => void;
  onChangeForm?: (event: any) => void;
};

function LoginForm ({submitLogin, onChangeForm}:Props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="text"
             onChange={onChangeForm} 
             className="form-control mainLoginInput"
              id="login" placeholder="логин | телефон"
               />
            <input 
            type="password"
            onChange={onChangeForm}
             className="form-control mainLoginInput"
              id="password" placeholder="пароль" />
            <button onClick={submitLogin} type="button" className="btn btn-dark mainLoginButton">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

не знаю как в интерфейсе написать обработку события и указать, что мне нужно передавать в метод параметр

```
name: string
```

То есть в идеале хочу сделать так:

```
interface Props {
  submitLogin?: () => void;
  onChangeForm?: (name: string) => void;
};
```

Но в этом случае ошибка:

```
(15,14): Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.
```

Подскажите как правильно передать метод в дочерний компонент, чтобы можно было ещё и параметр из колл бэка получить.

Answer (score 0):

`handleLoginFormChange` принимает строчку и вовзращает функцию, которая принимает `event`, но вы не вызываете `handleLoginFormChange`, когда передаете ее в качестве колбека в `onChange`.

```
interface Props {
  submitLogin?: () => void; 
  // onChangeForm возвращает функцию, которая принимает name
  onChangeForm?: (name: string) => (event: any) => void;
};

function LoginForm ({submitLogin, onChangeForm}:Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          {/* Вызываем onChangeForm с нужным name */}
          <input onChange={onChangeForm('login')} />
          <input  onChange={onChangeForm('password')} />
          <button onClick={submitLogin} type="button" className="btn btn-dark mainLoginButton">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```